# Running API call every 10 seconds

Tags: angular

I have the following method which returns an observable:

```js
getWhatsUp() {
    return this.http.get('user/whatsUp?token=' + this.getToken())
                  .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                 .catch(
        err => {
            this.checkToken(err);
            return Observable.throw('Unverified token');
            }
      );
}
```

I use it in my component the following way:

```js
ngOnInit() {
this.getWhatsUp();
}

getWhatsUp() {
    this.service.getWhatsUp()
                   .subscribe(
                     data => {
                        this.activities = data.activities;
                     },
                     error => { console.log("Error #333"); }
                     );
  }
```

How I can run it every 10 seconds to upate the activities and make sure the api call will not be stacked and run multiple times?

I know about `interval` method but i'm not sure how to use it in my setup

Answer (score 4):

Why not just:

```
ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => this.getWhatsUp, 10000);
}
```

If you need more information about the syntax, it's the [ES6 Arrow function again](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 2):

The RxJS way

```js
ngOnInit(){
  let sec = 10;
  Observable.timer(0, sec * 1000).subscribe(this.getWhatsUp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to create an additional function as a handler with setInterval included.  setInterval(myTimer, 10000)

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getWhatsUpHandler();
}

getWhatsUpHandler(){
    setInterval(getWhatsUp, 10000);
}

getWhatsUp() {
    this.service.getWhatsUp()
               .subscribe(
                 data => {
                    this.activities = data.activities;
                 },
                 error => { console.log("Error #333"); }
                 );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

A better solution is to use angular providers **$interval** and **$destroy**

Example : As this solution destroys call, if current state/ controller is changed

```
var stop=$interval(function () {
            function_call();
        }, 12000)

        $scope.stopInterval = function () {
            if (angular.isDefined(stop)) {
                $interval.cancel(stop);
                stop = undefined;
            }
        };

        $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
            // Make sure that the interval is destroyed too
            $scope.stopInterval();
        });
```